# What is the most standard approach to creating a separate menu which can be displayed over a single view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, viewcontroller

Apologize in advance as I'm still new to Xcode.

I have a 2D game build entirely in one viewController.  I would like to add both a start menu and in game menu to the game.  I assume the best way to do this is through another instance of a viewController?  Any advice or suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: You want to show a menu view only on this viewController?

Comment: yes thats right

Comment: Then add a view on it and remove that view when your task done.

Comment: This is totally basic but I actually don't know how to add a view.  Can you provide a simple example?

Comment: I am giving you an approach. Hope you will understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First place a `UIView` on your `Xib` or `UIStoryboard`.

Put 2 buttons on it and make their connections and outlets.

The view you want to open is view_Menu.( let us consider)
Now for managing view you need to do this:

```
view_Menu.frame = CGRectMake(xAxis, yAxis, self.view.frame.size.width, 150);
[self.view addSubView: view_Menu];
```

In xAxis and yAxis you can put your values.

Now when you click any button inside the menu view you can simply call this method:

```
[view_Menu RemoveFromSuperview];
```

So it will help to provide you that you want. A bit of things that you can put a background image or make some custom animations for better look.